# appending h2 to image with jquery

Tags: jquery

hi im trying to add a h2 with the title of an image after each image in my page... this is what ive got so far...

not really sure where im goin wrong

```
$("img[title]").each(function(){
   this.after("<h2>" . this.attr(title) "</h2>");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing JavaScript with php. Try:

```
$(this).after("<h2>" + $(this).attr('title') + "</h2>");
```